# form validation in JS for checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm trying to do a homework assignment and having some issues. I'm supposed to validate a form with Javascript. Right now I'm trying to make sure that a user has checked at least one checkbox (out of four options) in order for the form to submit. (I've gotten other segments of validation to work, so the issue seems to be local to this part of code.)

This is what the html for the checkbox form looks like:

```
<fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" name="boxes" id="member" value="member" />
    <label for="member">I'm a member.</label>

    <p><input type="checkbox" name="boxes" id="newsletter" value="newsletter" />
    <label for="newsletter">Please send me your monthly newsletter.</label></p>

    <p><input type="checkbox" name="boxes" id="preshow" value="preshow" />
    <label for="preshow">I'm interested in hearing about pre-show events.</label></p>

    <p><input type="checkbox" name="boxes" id ="none" value="none" />
    <label for="none">None of the above.</label></p>
```

And this is what I've written to try to validate it using Javascript:

```
function validateForm() {
  var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByName("boxes");
  for (var i=0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkBoxes[i].checked === true) {
        return true;
        break;
    } else {
        alert("At least one checkbox must be selected.");
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

This isn't working; the form submits whether boxes have been checked or not.
I would really love to get some help here because I don't have any idea what I'm doing wrong. Like I said, the problem seems to exist somewhere in this specific code, because other validation in separate blocks of code does work.

This is the complete HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title> hw5 </title>
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href="form.css"/>
    <script src="form.js"></script>
    <script src="states.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="browser.js"></script>-->
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
    <h1><b>Buy your tickets online</b></h1>
    <form name="theForm" method="post" action="https://cs101.cs.uchicago.edu/~sterner/show-data.php" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">
        <section id="name-and-address">
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="name">Full name</h2>
                <label for="firstname">First name:</label> <input type="text" name ="firstname" id="firstname" autofocus="autofocus" />
                <p><label for="lastname">Last name:</label> <input type="text" name ="lastname" id="lastname" /></p>
        </fieldset> 
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="Billing Address">Billing Address</h2>
                <label for="street">Street name and number:</label>
                    <input type="text" name ="street" id="street" />
                <p><label for="city">City:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" /></p>
                <p><label for="state">State:</label> 
                    <select id="state" name="state">
                    </select></p>
                <p><label for="zip">Zip code:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" /></p>
        </fieldset>
        </section>
        <section>
        <aside>
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="payMethod">Method of Payment</h2>
                <p class="row">
                    <input type="radio" id="pay-pal" name="payment" value="pay-pal" />
                    <label for="pay-pal">PayPal</label>
                </p>
                <p class="row">
                    <input type="radio" id="credit" name="payment" value="credit" />
                    <label for="credit">Credit Card</label>
                </p>
        </fieldset> 
        <fieldset>
                <input type="checkbox" name="boxes" id="member" value="member" />
                    <label for="member">I'm a member.</label>
                <p><input type="checkbox" name="boxes" id="newsletter" value="newsletter" />
                    <label for="newsletter">Please send me your monthly newsletter.</label></p>
                <p><input type="checkbox" name="boxes" id="preshow" value="preshow" />
                    <label for="preshow">I'm interested in hearing about pre-show events.</label></p>
                <p><input type="checkbox" name="boxes" id ="none" value="none" />
                    <label for="none">None of the above.</label></p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
                <p><label for="email">Email address:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" /></p>
        </fieldset>
        </aside>
        </section>
        <section id="submit">
        <fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Buy my tickets."/>
        </fieldset>
        </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You missed out the bit where you call the function.

Comment: This is actually just a small part of a much bigger validating function, which is called when the form is submitted, so the I wrote the call in the HTML inside of the <form> tag (<form onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">) well before I get to the checkboxes... and it works fine for other sections of the validating function, just not for this one.

Comment: Does it make sense to validate a bunch of things with one function this way..? Maybe that's why things aren't working? I should break it up into several functions?

Comment: What do you mean by "when the form is submitted"? At `POST` time, it is too late. You should do the whole validation thing on change of any field of the form and only when validations pass enable the `submit` button...

Comment: What I mean is when the submit button is clicked, the validation function runs and should stop submission if there are any errors

Comment: @kayev check my updated answer.